# ASP If Statement for Setting Param

Tags: pdf, vbscript, asp-classic

Using [ASPPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/), I am creating a pdf form from user input.

When the user selects a radio option, I am able to set where the data will write within the PDF like this.

```
If Request("type") = 1 Then x=57
If Request("type") = 1 Then y=506 else
If Request("type") = 2 Then x=57
If Request("type") = 2 Then y=400 else

Page1.Canvas.SetParams "color=black, linewidth=2"
Page1.Canvas.DrawLine x, y, x + 7, y - 7
Page1.Canvas.DrawLine x, y - 7, x + 7, y
```

This generates an X mark in an appropriate box in my PDF.

My problem is that the value of those fields needs to be a string, not a number. When I try this, I do not receive any errors but it also doesn't write anything.

```
If Request("type") = AP Then x=57
If Request("type") = AP Then y=506 else
If Request("type") = AR Then x=57
If Request("type") = AR Then y=400 else

Page1.Canvas.SetParams "color=black, linewidth=2"
Page1.Canvas.DrawLine x, y, x + 7, y - 7
Page1.Canvas.DrawLine x, y - 7, x + 7, y
```

I am not able to simply change the values within the form to numbers as those same values are used in multiple places throughout the script and I need it as that value, not a number.

I've also tried adding " " (quotes) around the value, but that doesn't work either.

```
... 
If Request("type") = "AP" Then x=57
...
```

Any help out there?

Comment: What do you get when you do `Response.Write(Request("type"))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong structured `if .. then .. else` statement. Right syntax is as follows:

```
' Single-Line syntax:
If condition Then statements [Else elsestatements ] 

' Or, you can use the block form syntax: 
If condition Then
   [statements]
[ElseIf condition-n Then
   [elseifstatements]] . . .
[Else
   [elsestatements]]
End If
```

Hence, your code snipped could be as follows:

```
If UCase(Request("type")) = "AP" Then 
  x=57
  y=506
ElseIf UCase(Request("type")) = "AR" Then
  x=57
  y=400
Else
  '
End If
```

Or

```
Select Case UCase(Request("type"))
    Case "AP" 
        x=57
        y=506
    Case "AR"
        x=57
        y=400
    Case Else
        '
End Select
```

Note: `UCase` function returns a string that has been converted to uppercase, as we could *not know* which letter case the `Request("type")` is (e.g. `ap`, `aP`, `Ap` or `AP`?).

Resource: [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Your UCase solution worked. I'm doing a happy dance!